# Spring Cloud Stream: class [B cannot be cast to class

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I have two services A and B. I want A to send a message and B to answer with multiple messages in return. I created the following classes as messages to go across the bus:

The **base class** for all messages:

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({ 
    @Type(value = PointUpdate.class, name = "PointUpdate"),
    @Type(value = PublishAll.class, name = "PublishAll")
})
public abstract class Message {

    public abstract String getType();
    
}
```

The **PublishAll** message that service A sends to initiate the response:

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({ 
    @Type(value = PublishAll.class, name = "PublishAll")
})
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
public abstract class Command extends Message {

}

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PublishAll extends Command {

    private final String type = "PublishAll";
    
}
```

The **PointUpdate** message service B responds with:

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({ 
    @Type(value = PointUpdate.class, name = "PointUpdate")
})
public abstract class Event extends Message {

}

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class PointUpdate extends Event {

    private String extension;
    
    private String identifier;
    
    private final String type = "PointUpdate";
    
    private IPoint point;
    
}
```

This is the error I see repeatedly in service A. Short version:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class [B cannot be cast to class io.symphony.common.messages.event.PointUpdate ([B is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; io.symphony.common.messages.event.PointUpdate is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @21d7259f)
```

Long version:

```
2022-01-08 13:59:01.735 ERROR 40817 --- [xqW6MUV9OzUfQ-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionToDestinationBinder$1@47a9f8f1]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: class [B cannot be cast to class io.symphony.common.messages.event.PointUpdate ([B is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; io.symphony.common.messages.event.PointUpdate is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @21d7259f), failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[604], headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedExchange=status, amqp_deliveryTag=1, deliveryAttempt=3, amqp_consumerQueue=status.anonymous.H5ZEiQThQxqW6MUV9OzUfQ, amqp_redelivered=false, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=status, amqp_timestamp=Sat Jan 08 13:58:58 CET 2022, amqp_messageId=b83226d8-e91c-9d06-cda8-d0ee2aa7895f, id=52de941e-ee43-68e2-5ffb-68f2a3387226, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-iQgeMzEpmbs4zXk67-AjFA, sourceData=(Body:'[B@6496140e(byte[604])' MessageProperties [headers={}, timestamp=Sat Jan 08 13:58:58 CET 2022, messageId=b83226d8-e91c-9d06-cda8-d0ee2aa7895f, contentType=application/json, contentLength=0, receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, priority=0, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=status, receivedRoutingKey=status, deliveryTag=1, consumerTag=amq.ctag-iQgeMzEpmbs4zXk67-AjFA, consumerQueue=status.anonymous.H5ZEiQThQxqW6MUV9OzUfQ]), contentType=application/json, timestamp=1641646738687}]
    at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:191)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:65)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:208)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.access$1300(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.lambda$onMessage$0(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:374)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:329)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:225)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:370)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1665)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1584)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1572)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1563)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1507)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:967)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:914)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:83)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1291)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1197)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class [B cannot be cast to class io.symphony.common.messages.event.PointUpdate ([B is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; io.symphony.common.messages.event.PointUpdate is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @21d7259f)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.invokeConsumer(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:784)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.doApply(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:589)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.apply(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:435)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.PartitionAwareFunctionWrapper.apply(PartitionAwareFunctionWrapper.java:79)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionWrapper.apply(FunctionConfiguration.java:717)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionToDestinationBinder$1.handleMessageInternal(FunctionConfiguration.java:559)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56)
    ... 27 more
```

It appears that the `PublishAll` message from service A reaches service B, service B responds with something that service A cannot convert into a `PointUpdate` message.

I know this is probably not enough for anyone to pin point the mistake I made, but I have no idea how to further troubleshoot. I made sure all the pojos have a default constructor, I set the jackson annotations right for proper serialization and deserialization. No idea what else to look at. Please help and I'll update this post with information.

Comment: Hi, I have the same error! the scenario is different, though! did you find any solution or do you know why it's happening?

Comment: Did you find out what was the issue?

Answer (score 0):

In our case one of the classes that was used for deserializing the message didn't have a default constructor because it had Lombok's [@Builder](https://www.projectlombok.org/features/Builder) annotation but was missing the [@NoArgsConstructor](https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor) annotation. Keep in mind that [@Builder](https://www.projectlombok.org/features/Builder) adds a package-private constructor with all fields as arguments.  For whatever reason the root cause was not included in the stack trace's log.

A simple test would be to try to serialize & deserialize using the class PointUpdate checking particularly the IPoint attribute whose class/interface code is not present in the excerpt.